# Aggregation of values in a given range (interval) with SPARQL?

Tags: optimization, sparql, rdf, linked-data

Say in an RDF dataset, there are a set of values that range from 0 to 100 (for example, percentages). I want to count the number of values in a given range, for example, 100 - 90 | 90 - 80 | ... | 10 - 0. The output I expect looks like the following:

```
╔════════════════╦════════╗
║     Range      ║ Count  ║
╠════════════════╬════════╣
║ 100 >= x < 90  ║ 4521   ║
║ 90 >= x < 80   ║ 650    ║
║     ...        ║ ...    ║
║ 10 >= x <= 0   ║ 2650   ║
╚════════════════╩════════╝
```

I am currently using SPARQL subqueries and filters to get to the solution. But this seems a common use case and my intuition tells me that there should be a better way to do this. Is there a better (or more efficient) way to reach this answer?

What current solution looks like the following.

```
PREFIX dqv: <http://www.w3.org/ns/dqv#>
select distinct ?count90_100 ?count80_90 ?count10_0  where  {
 ?m a dqv:QualityMeasurement .
 { select count(?m) as ?count90_100 where { ?m dqv:value ?value FILTER (?value > 90 && ?value <= 100) }}
 { select count(?m) as ?count80_90 where { ?m dqv:value ?value FILTER (?value > 80 && ?value <= 90) }}
 { select count(?m) as ?count10_0 where { ?m dqv:value ?value FILTER (?value >= 0 && ?value <= 10) }}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a **values** block to specify the upper and lower bounds on the ranges and to get an "id" for each range "id".  Then you can group on that range.  E.g.,

```sql
select ?rangeId (count(?x) as ?numMatches) {
  values (?rangeId ?min ?max) { (0 0 10)
                               (1 10 20)
                               #-- ...
                               (8 80 90)
                               (9 90 100) }

  #-- query that finds a value for ?x...

  filter (?min <= ?x && ?x < ?max)
}
group by ?rangeId
```